# Python/MySQL - Fetching only 5 lines of the query and if user presses a letter it shows next 5 lines and so on

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

Working on a python app connecting to a movies database in mysql:
Looking to show first 5 lines from the query, if the user presses anything besides from q(will bring back to main menu) it will fetch next 5 lines and so on. So far I have :

```
with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = "select FilmName,ActorName from Film,Actor,FilmCast where Film.FilmID = FilmCast.CastFilmID and FilmCast.CastActorID = Actor.ActorID order by FilmName ASC,ActorName ASC LIMIT 5;"
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        button = str(input('Press Q to quit'))
        if button == 'q':
            main()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you want to use the concept of [OFFSET](https://www.guru99.com/limit.html).
Use a `counter` variable to keep track of your row number on each user input, and the use that in your `query`.

Here's the code

```
offset = 0
with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        limit = 5
        query = """select FilmName,ActorName from Film,Actor,FilmCast
                   where Film.FilmID = FilmCast.CastFilmID 
                   and FilmCast.CastActorID = Actor.ActorID 
                   order by FilmName ASC,
                   ActorName ASC LIMIT {0}, {1};""".format(offset, limit)
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        button = str(input('Press Q to quit'))
        if button == 'q':
            main()
        else:
            offset += 1
```